# Trouble making my script print the result

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, web-scraping

I've created a scipt in python using class to collect the question links from a webpage. I used `__str__()` method within my script to print the results. However, when I try to print it, I get None as an output.

The main purpose here is to make `__str__()` this method work in my following script.

Where I'm going wrong and how can I fix it?

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"

class DataSourcer:

    def __init__(self,link):
        self.link = link
        self.datalist = []

    def fetch(self):
        res = requests.get(self.link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
        for ilink in soup.select(".summary .question-hyperlink"):
            self.datalist.append(urljoin(self.link,ilink.get("href")))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.datalist

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    crawler = DataSourcer(URL)
    print(crawler.fetch())
```

Comment: i'm not familiar with using classes, trying to learn that so this is a good one for me to see if someone posts an answer. so this could be wrong, but nothing is being returned in your fetch() function. so maybe that's why?

Comment: *"I get None as an output. "*: This is because `.fetch(...` returns `None`. Add as last line into `.fetch(...` => `return self`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is fine, it seems like you are printing it incorrectly. You are printing `crawler.fetch()` which returns `None`.

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"

class DataSourcer:

    def __init__(self,link):
        self.link = link
        self.datalist = []

    def fetch(self):
        res = requests.get(self.link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
        for ilink in soup.select(".summary .question-hyperlink"):
            self.datalist.append(urljoin(self.link,ilink.get("href")))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.datalist

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    crawler = DataSourcer(URL)
    crawler.fetch()
    print(crawler.__str__())
```

Comment: Wow, no. 

Doing so you completely loose sense of .__str__ method. Now you rely on list.__str__() not DataSources.__str__()

Answer (score 1):

You are not printing right thing. Please check documentation how to use such methods.

```
crawler = DataSourcer(URL)
crawler.fetch() 
print(crawler)
```

Comment: This is what I get complying your suggestion `TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type list)` @Koral.

Comment: oh, please rewrite:

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.datalist)

Comment: There is still some problem if I rewrite that method as you suggested @Koral. Because, I can't iterate through the list if I wanted to reuse them whereas I can easily do the same using `for link in crawler.__str__(): print(link)`.

Comment: @robots.txt - hmm I understand, but please consider using __iter__ method if You want to iterate. Method __str__ should return string (!) and you should have no possibility to iterate over it. 

You approach will work, however, it is not good idea to do it this way - it is far from clear code and makes code much incomprehensible :)

Answer (score 0):

print(crawler.fetch()) will print the return value of the fetch() method (it has no return value)
What you should do is:

```
crawler.fetch()
print(crawler)
```